# Sitecore 7 and MVC 4 integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7

What is the best way to integrate an MVC 4 solution into a Sitecore 7 instance when the solution is located outside of the website's root?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your starting point is going to be the [Sitecore MVC Developers reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/MVC%20Reference.aspx) and there was a great video tutorial posted which is a step by step: [Sitecore MVC - Getting Started (Part 1)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3Mwcphtz4w).

You may also want to read:

- [John West's Sitecore MVC blog posts](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/06/Sitecore-MVC-Playground-Part-1-Enable-MVC.aspx), these are mainly related to Sitecore 6.6 but a lot of the theory is still the same.
- [Learning Sitecore MVC](http://www.alen.me.uk/2012/08/learning-sitecore-mvc-part-1.html)
- [Getting started with Sitecore MVC as asp.net mvc developer](http://www.robertgray.net.au/posts/getting-started-with-sitecore-mvc-as-an-aspnet-mvc-developer)

There are plenty of other posts, you need to Google these, don't expect a comprehensive list to be posted on SO. If you are not familiar with MVC then you need to read, learn and understand the techniques. It's not greatly different from ASP.Net but a slightly different mindset and way of doing things. This is not Sitecore specific, you will find plenty of tutorials online.

Comment: Thanks this will help a lot!

Comment: Part 2 & 3 of that video is on the way. Check out the [MVC3 Intro videos on Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro) too.

Comment: Part 2 came out a short while ago
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dW_rQp9bMmE

Comment: @jammykam  Am new to this site core and i have been assigned a task to creating new events and event listing using sitecore CMS keystone(dey want it using controller rendering ) am not getting any crude operation documents could you please help me to get some documents related to this